# PAC file with dnsDomainIs on cellular network?

Tags: mobile-network, proxy

My country started blocking access to some sites, so I'm trying to setup my devices to bypass it. I decided to use proxy via PAC file, because I don't want to reroute all my traffic just to access couple of sites. Following *.pac is working on Windows but I'm not able to find a way to use it on Android (or to at least to use proxy/vpn only for specific sites). I heard that Firefox on Android supports PAC files, but it's super slow compared to Chromium based browsers (at least on my not super fast device).

Autoproxy and ProxyDroid apps don't accept this PAC file and Drony (if I understood correctly) requires input of it's proxy address in APN settings which causes disappearance of mobile internet on my operator.

my PAC file:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
 if (dnsDomainIs(host, "somesite.com")) {
    return "HTTPS someproxy.com:9050; PROXY someproxy.com:9050; DIRECT";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

I have root, busybox, xposed.

Comment: No need for change anything in APN. Drony uses vpn mode to intercept all traffic. Give it a try.

Comment: @SandroProxysupport Oh, I was kinda hesitant to bother you because of that 8) I've tried Drony but wasn't able to access any site after enabling it's VPN. Do you have any idea of what can it be? I took some screenshots of Drony configuration https://someimage.com/RFHF

Comment: Maybe uses ipv6 that is not supported. Try to switch to ipv4 in APN settings.

Comment: @SandroProxysupport ipv4 is already set by default..

Comment: Then no idea what's going on. Maybe vpn mode is not working okey. Send mail to help you more